# IOS How to take screenshot of only image in uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to take screenshot of only image in imageview. I have tried following code but it will take screenshot of imageview .

```
CGRect grabRect = CGRectMake(self.vwBackup.frame.origin.x,self.vwBackup.frame.origin.y,self.vwBackup.frame.size.width,self.vwBackup.frame.size.height);

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
    }
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   // UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
    self.ImgEditableView.image=viewImage;
```

Here i have attached image of taken screenshot with above code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.displayImageView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.displayImageView.bounds.size);

[self.displayImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
if(imgData)
{
    [imgData writeToFile:@"screenshot.png" atomically:YES];
}
else

    NSLog(@"error while taking screenshot");
```

Comment: I have tried updated code but now, it will take full screenshot means it included imageview also. I need screenshot of only size of image which is in imageview.